# How do I position fixed-position div to % width inside main app div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to edit my React chat room app so that the main App div is 80% width of the page, and everything inside is set to either 25% width or 75% width. I am tryin to set my left (room list) column to 25% width of the App div and (basically everything else) the top section, message section, and new message form to 75% width of the App div.

My issue is that I'm setting the room list column and my position fixed elements (top user section and bottom message input section) are taking 100% or 75% of the entire screen. How do I get them to only take 75% of the app (parent/container) AND stay fixed to the top/bottom??

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apTGg.png)

App (parent/container) CSS:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

top current room display:

```
.currentRoomDisplay {
  z-index: 15;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 25%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #e0ebfc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top:0px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

messageBar on bottom:

```
.messageBar {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 388px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    width: inherit;
    background-color: #e0ebfc;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 40px;  
    overflow: scroll; 
}
```

I've been trying stuff for hours! please help! :D

**If you need me to copy/paste everything, I will

*******UPDATE**********
got it figured out, thanks for the help!
I fixed it at 3am so I cant remember exactly what I did but I'll save this for future reference. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard about CSS flexbox layout?

CSS:

```
.App {
    ... (other styles)
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.listRoom {
    ... (other styles)
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 25%;   
}

.currentRoomBox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 75%;
}

.currentRoomDisplay {
    ... (other styles)
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-basis: 100%;   
}

.messageBar {
    ... (other styles)
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-basis: 100%;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<div className="App>
    <div className="listRoom">
        ...
    </div>
    <div className="currentRoomBox">
        <div className="currentRoomDisplay">
        </div>
        <div className="messageBar">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this CSS:

```
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box
 }
```